# create html table with php

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

i'm kind off stuck in this:

mysql table : tableexample with the columns ( flightnumber, company, datearrive, timeleave, timearrive)

**Where I generate a array like this:**

```
Array[0]

 - Array[0][1] => 1000
 - Array[0][2] => Company A
 - Array[0][3] => 2014-05-10
 - Array[0][4] => 10:00:00
 - Array[0][5] => 15:00:00  

Array[1]

 - Array[1][1] => 2000
 - Array[1][2] => Company A
 - Array[1][3] => 2014-05-11
 - Array[1][4] => 10:00:00
 - Array[1][5] => 15:00:00  

Array[2]

 - Array[2][1] => 3000
 - Array[2][2] => Company B
 - Array[2][3] => 2014-05-10
 - Array[2][4] => 10:00:00
 - Array[2][5] => 15:00:00  

Array[3]

 - Array[3][1] => 4000
 - Array[3][2] => Company B
 - Array[3][3] => 2014-05-11
 - Array[3][4] => 16:00:00
 - Array[0][5] => 19:00:00
```

**Then I need to place this in a html table:**

```
<p>....................| 2014-05-10|2014-05-11 |</p>
<p>10:00:00 - 15:00:00 | Company A |...........|</p>
<p>10:00:00 - 15:00:00 | Company B | Company A |</p>
<p>16:00:00 - 19:00:00 | ..........| Company B |</p>
```

**I've already:**

populate the head of the table with the dates, but now i'm stuck....

```
<thead>
   <?php
     echo "<tr>";
     for ($row = 0; $row <  5;) {
       $dia=$array[$row][2];
       echo "<th>Dia " . $dia . "</th>";
       $i=$row;
       for ($rownext = ($row+1); $rownext < 5;){
         if ($array[$rownext][2]==$dia){
             $i++;
         };
         $rownext++;
       };
       $row=($i+1);
      };
      echo "</tr>";
    ?>
</thead>
```

Comment: the great dificulty is that the table is pouplated um rows....if it was in columns that would be easier in this case

Comment: Show us how you populated the headers

Comment: I would first build a tabular array with time intervals as keys.

Comment: just fyi, you dont need `;` after `}`, just `}` is sufficient, just a style thing :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be a lot neater, but I've tried to keep things as separated as possible and commented throughout so you can understand how it works. This looks like it should do the trick:

```
$details = array(
  1 => array(
      1 => 1000,
      2 => 'Company A',
      3 => '2014-05-10',
      4 => '10:00:00',
      5 => '15:00:00',
  ),
  2 => array(
      1 => 1000,
      2 => 'Company A',
      3 => '2014-05-11',
      4 => '10:00:00',
      5 => '15:00:00',
  ),
  3 => array(
      1 => 1000,
      2 => 'Company B',
      3 => '2014-05-10',
      4 => '10:00:00',
      5 => '15:00:00',
  ),
  4 => array(
      1 => 1000,
      2 => 'Company B',
      3 => '2014-05-11',
      4 => '16:00:00',
      5 => '19:00:00',
  )
);

// Format our data into something we can use more easily
$flight_dates = array();
$times = array();
$dates = array();
foreach ($details as $flight_details) {
  $company_name = $flight_details[2];
  $date = $flight_details[3];
  $time = $flight_details[4] . ' - ' . $flight_details[5];

  // Keep a unique record of each date, and the times of flights
  $dates[$date] = 1;
  $times[$time] = 1;

  // Record which date/time each company is flying
  $flight_dates[$date][$time][] = $company_name;
}

// Create the table header
$html = '<table border="1">';
$html .= '<thead>';
$html .= '<tr>';
$html .= '<th>&nbsp;</th>';
foreach ($dates as $date => $value1) {
  $html .= '<th>' . $date . '</th>';
}
$html .= '</tr>';

// Create the rows in the table
foreach ($times as $time => $value1) { // Loop through each flight time
  $html .= '<tr>';
  $html .= '<td>' . $time . '</td>'; // The first column is always the time
  foreach ($dates as $date => $value2) { // Loop through each date
      if (!empty($flight_dates[$date][$time])) { // Check if flights exist at the current time
        $html .= '<td>' . implode(', ', $flight_dates[$date][$time]) . '</td>'; // List companies
      } else { // No flights
        $html .= '<td>&nbsp;</td>'; // Leave cell blank
      }
  }
  $html .= '</tr>';
}
$html .= '</table>';

echo $html;
```

Made a [codepad](http://codepad.org/M9PmZW2x) with it, doesn't display as a table which is annoying, but you can copy the html output it gives you and see what it looks like.

Comment: @MLeFevre tks so much, great code :) I nedded it to place one value in each cell because i'm doing a JS onclick to open the record in other page. But I'll get it from here. Tks a lot again.

Comment: And for the abuse... @MLeFevre , i'm trying to ajust the code to repeat the line with the time if there are two companys on the same day and time, but I'm having some problems.... a litle more help?